# Is there any way to randomize padding in CSS/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface

So I've been trying to make a web-app and thought it would be cool to have "cards" with randomized top padding.

Here's a screen-shot of what I'm trying to achieve:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvgDP.jpg

And here's what I have:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/K34mo.jpg

This is the JavaScript I tried to use, but it failed.

```
document.getElementById("card").addEventListener("load", randomCards);
let root = document.card;

function randomCards() {
    root.style.setProperty('cardpadding-top', Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + "px");
});
```

And here's the HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="scroll-wrap">
        <div id="card"></div>
        <div id="card"></div>
        <div id="card"></div>
        <div id="card"></div>
        <div id="card"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: could you share your HTML code as well. for more clarity :)

Comment: you should get hold of all of your cards and assign each one of them a random padding.

Comment: I'll see if that works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how to do it. I have used `class="card"` instead of `id` and also used `querySelectorAll()` to get all the cards and loop over each and set the styles randomly using `Math.random()`.

```
document.querySelectorAll(".card").forEach(card=>{
  card.style.paddingTop = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + "px"
})
```

**WORKING CODE DEMO:**

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".card").forEach(card=>{
  card.style.paddingTop = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + "px"
})
```

```css
.scroll-wrap{ height:400px; display:flex; align-items:center}
.card{
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  background:blue;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:0 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll-wrap">
        <div class="card"></div>
        <div class="card"></div>
        <div class="card"></div>
        <div class="card"></div>
        <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: U are most welcome Kuru. Always here to help my fellow developers. It's 5:13 am in my country but coding and helping people is my passion and you can say hobby :)

Comment: What's up with the `100` passed in `Math.random(100)`?

Comment: Ohhh, Sorry Typo, My bad. let me update. Thanks for pointing

Answer (score 1):

Based on your example, you should try this, swap id with class attribute go through each of your div's and assign random paddings.

JS

```
 document.addEventListener("load", randomCards);
 function randomCards() {
   document.querySelectorAll('.card').forEach(card => {
     card.style.paddingTop = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + "px";
   });
 }
```

HTML

```
 <div class="scroll-wrap">
        <div class="card"></div>
        <div class="card"></div>
        <div class="card"></div>
        <div class="card"></div>
        <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I would also set your as a solution but it only lets me set one answer as a solution :( I will set it as useful though! :)